# Netbeans preventing Java from accessing network drive

Tags: java, netbeans, network-drive

**This is the Java code I'm using to test:**

package sandbox;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class Sandbox {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ScriptException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    File folder = new File("Z:\\Job Logging\\addToDb");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Here are the results:**
[image]

[image]

Netbeans >> About:

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101)
Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.2 Patch 2
Java: 1.8.0_91; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.91-b14
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_91-b14
System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_US (nb)
```

Windows 10 Pro (This issue never occurred in my machines running Windows 7)
I also find that using Subprocess, I can launch external applications, but not Python.

Comment: Is the network drive samba based?

Comment: Try renaming the folder you are trying to access in this form **\\Server\shared_folder**. See this SO answer: \\Server\shared_folder

Comment: @MadProgrammer, the network drive is not samba based.

I created a new project in IntelliJ and imported all of the java classes and everything is now working.

Comment: @skomisa, I also tried that to no avail.